Announcing the January–February 2025 topic challenge: Jhumpa Lahiri
In accordance with our meta agreement to have topic challenges
and a later meta agreement to have topic challenges lasting for two months and overlapping by one month,
it is time to announce the January–February 2025 topic challenge.
Based on the number of votes (+4), our 88th topic challenge will be
the works of Jhumpa Lahiri

What's a topic challenge?
See the meta posts linked above, and also this main Meta post.
In short, during January and February 2025 you are invited to try to get hold of one or more of the works by Jhumpa Lahiri, read them, and ask or answer questions about them.
Participation is not obligatory in any sense, and questions on other works are more than welcome during January and February too;
they just won't count as part of this topic challenge.
How can I take part?
By getting hold of one or more of the works by Jhumpa Lahiri and

asking good questions about it or
answering questions that have been posted as part of this challenge or
submitting a book review to our Tumblr blog.

Questions about these works should be tagged with jhumpa-lahiri, a tag for any book-length work and, if the work is in Italian, italian-language.
We'll keep a list of all such questions in an answer to this meta post.
Below is Rand al'Thor's
presentation:

This Pulitzer Prizewinner has written both novels and short stories, in at least two languages (English and Italian), as well as doing translation work. Many of her works focus on the lives of (nth-generation) immigrants from India to the US, such as her first short story collection:

The stories address sensitive dilemmas in the lives of Indians or Indian immigrants, with themes such as marital difficulties, the bereavement over a stillborn child, and the disconnection between first and second generation United States immigrants. Lahiri later wrote, "When I first started writing I was not conscious that my subject was the Indian-American experience. What drew me to my craft was the desire to force the two worlds I occupied to mingle on the page as I was not brave enough, or mature enough, to allow in life."

Her second short story collection "achieved the rare distinction of debuting at number 1 on The New York Times best seller list", so she's far from an unknown author, but there have been no questions about her works on this site so far. She's won multiple literary awards, and recently made headlines for declining one such award for reasons of principle. It would be interesting to read her works, examine their cultural backdrop, and even think about their intertextual relations with other works (for example, one of her Italian short story collections was titled after another collection by Alberto Moravia).

What's next?

Vote for the next topic challenge or propose your own!


List of all questions posted in this topic challenge
1.
2.
3.
100. add entries in the form https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/mm/2024.

The highest-voted of these is question-url with a score of TBD at the end of February.
The most viewed is question-url, with approximately TBD views by the end of February.
TBD questions received at least one answer.

Reviews submitted to our Tumblr blog: TBD.
